# Spring MVC a href redirect to another page doesnt work

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I am new in Spring MVC. I was practising with some example. And I am experiencing some problems.
When I run my project i get : `HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config`.
Thanks in advance..

I have the following file:

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SpringExamples</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="Controller" />
    <mvc:resources location="/assets/" mapping="/assets/**"/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <import resource="dispatcher-servlet.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Controller.

```
package Controller;
@Controller
public class RedirectController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index(){
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/login"> test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

WEB-INF/pages/login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<b>This is login html</b>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add this dependency to your `pom.xml` file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```